# Duplicate a page

Tags: google-docs

I read on multiple websites that, in order to duplicate a page in Google Docs, you should go `File / Make a Copy`

But I'm pretty certain that duplicates the entire document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> read on multiple websites that, in order to duplicate a page in Google Docs, you should go File / Make a Copy
>
> But I'm pretty certain that duplicates the entire document

You are correct.  If it is a one page document that works great ;-)

Google Docs, like most word processing apps, is designed around the concept of text that flows between pages automatically shifting to adapt to additional text as well as printer page sizes, and other output preferences.

Pages are not separate entities to be copied and pasted.  Rather you need to copy the `page content` and paste it on a new page.  The page content could however include explicit page breaks which would be *like* copying a page if you placed that somewhere in the same document.